# key example for item in nsdictionary array objective c

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, predicate, key-value-coding

I have an array of dictionaries containing some values and keys.suppose keys k1,k2,k3,k4 etc...
from this array I need to find object for key k1 for which I know the object of key k3 of the same dictionary.
Is there any method without using iteration that means by using predicates or keyvalue coding(KVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without searching the array, since `k3` doesn't have any way of knowing it is used as a key in one of the dictionaries. In fact, it could be used as a key in more than one dictionary.

Comment: not with that key the object of that key. Its unique because its an id

Comment: @Johnykutty In your case, the objects may be unique, but in general, they need not be. Thus, there is no language mechanism to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to iterate over the array, check for key `k3`and return `k1`if you've found a match.